# Python and Sqlite3 return more than one line

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to do a query in sqlite with python, but when I do the research in my database it's just return the last input. Like this

```
def Busca(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('teste.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        valorAtual = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
        if valorAtual == "CNPJ":
            sqlqry = 'SELECT * FROM OrdemServico WHERE CNPJ =' + self.lineEdit_9.text()
            c = cursor.execute(sqlqry)
            retorno = str(c.fetchone())
            retorno = retorno.replace("'","")
            self.textEdit.setText(retorno)
```

So this query in sqlite browser returns three values, but in python it just return one.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: You should use `retorno = str(c.fetchall())` to get all the results. It would be nice to read the docs as people suggested in the answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the documentation carefully to see what you are trying to do:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone

Also, here is a blog post around what you are trying to do that uses 'fetchone'. You are pretty much **not** handling your result set properly.

This isn't using the exact module you are using, but the idea is the same.

http://kushaldas.in/posts/fetching-row-by-row-from-mysql-in-python.html

Comment: Thanks, I need to use fetchall()